# Action Function was not working

Tags: visualforce, actionfunction

I am calling apex method via action Function but it was not calling in IE. Same code works fine in chrome.

```
 function disableButton() {
          j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

          j$('[id$="cmdSearch"]').toggleClass('btnDisabled', true).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      }

      function enableButton() {
          j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

          j$('[id$="cmdSearch"]').removeClass("btnDisabled");
          j$('[id$="cmdSearch"]').prop('disabled', false);
          return false;
      }

 <apex:commandButton id="cmdSearch" value="Search" onclick="disableButton(); searchMethod();"> 
    <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" reRender="pdf"/>
 </apex:commandButton>

 <apex:actionFunction name="searchMethod" action="{!search}" oncomplete="enableButton(); return false;" reRender="pageMsg,resultId"/>
```

Comment: Could you please share the code ?

Comment: In IE , without oncomplete and reRender in <apex:actionFunction>, it was working